# .slideToggle nested ajax repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that writes out to a cooke the value of the DIV that holds that data that I want to show, the cookie code works, the toggle code works but when the page refreshses, I can get the list of repeater elements, itterate through them, determine if the section should be hidden or not but I can't use visible, I can't use .show() or .hide(), I know this has to be easy but what am I over looking???

This is my working code for the slidetoggle that works and writes the true or false to the cooke based on the repeater title attribute:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.toggle").click(function () {
            var inObj = $(this).parent().find('div#fader');
            var inTitle = inObj.attr('title');
            inObj.slideToggle('fast', function () {
                docCookies.setItem(inTitle, inObj.is(':visible').toString());
            });
        });
    });
```

This is the code block that I have the problem with, specifically, the .show() and the .hide() are not known methods, so I have the object in inObj[] collection, I am not sure how to cast this or deal with this in javascript.....

```
 $(window).load(function () {
        var inObj = $('div#fader');
        for (var i = 0; i < inObj.length; i++) {
            var objTitle = inObj[i].title;
            var item = docCookies.getItem(objTitle);
            if (item == "true") {
                inObj[i].show();
            }
            else {
                 inObj[i].hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(inObj[i]).show()` and `$(inObj[i]).hide()`.

Comment: YES!!! I would upvote this but I don't have rep enough to do it, but this FIXED my problem! YOU ROCK! Now my nested repeater within a nested repeater works exactly as I need it to!THANKS